# How do I get the control button to work in the terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pantheon-terminal

How do I get the control button to work in the terminal? control-shift-c does not copy, control-q does not kill processes, and without use of the control key I am finding it impossible to use nano or vim. I am used to coding with the MacOS terminal command line. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!
I think the key mappings were thinking that my keyboard was a full-size iMac keyboard instead of the Macbook Pro keyboard. I followed the first part of this tutorial and it fixed the problem! https://medium.com/@petrstepanov/a-macos-like-keyboard-remap-on-ubuntu-linux-cae1d108a97

I switched the xkb mapping for command and control. This worked like a charm and I am so relieved. The actual physical control key on my keyboard still isn't working, so I think that particular piece of hardware might be broken, but now that the left command key has been mapped to control's functionality, I can do everything I need to within the terminal.

Comment: If this resolve your problem you should mark your question as answered, so more people can see it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the terminal window, you should see the shortcut and commands. 
Can you re-try after validating that you're using the correct keys?

Also, can you screenshot what you see in that window when you right-click? 
thanks!

Comment: Thanks for asking! There are no shortcut and command options when I right click within the terminal, though... :/

Answer (score 0):

There's a Preferences pull-down menu in the upper-right corner (shaped like a gear), which has an entry "Natural Copy/Paste".  Switching this off will switch copy/paste from Ctrl-C to Ctrl-Shift-C etc.